# IntentService is buggy on Android 4.2 (Jelly Bean)?

Tags: android, service

I am programming an application that needs to sync up with a remote server every minute. There is no way to use push notifications since an app is intended for internal use and it is not going to be published on Google Play.
I found out that I can use AlarmManager and IntentService to reach my objective. So I schedule pending intent to be delivered every minute and handle it in IntentService to perform network I/O. It sounds pretty simple but I faced following problem: app fails with the following error after some period of time (I suppose about 100 minutes).

```
05-27 06:52:05.845 32176-32732/ru.infotecs.intentservice E/Looper: WARNING: The Looper class instance count has over a limit(100). There should be some leakage of Looper or HandlerThread.
05-27 06:52:05.845 32176-32732/ru.infotecs.intentservice E/Looper: Looper class instance count = 101
05-27 06:52:05.845 32176-32732/ru.infotecs.intentservice E/Looper: Current Thread Name: IntentService[BackgroundService]
```

I created very simple example to inspect the problem closer. So it looks like:

Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private AlarmManager alarmManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(getBaseContext(), 0, BackgroundService.getIntent(getBaseContext()), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 0, 500, pi);
    }
}
```

Service:

```
public class BackgroundService extends IntentService {
    private final static String TAG = BackgroundService.class.getSimpleName();
    private final static String ACTION_START = "ru.infotecs.intentservice.action.START";
    private static volatile int counter = 0;

    public BackgroundService() {
        super(TAG);
        counter = 0;
    }

    public static Intent getIntent(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, BackgroundService.class);
        intent.setAction(ACTION_START);
        return intent;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            if (ACTION_START.equals(action)) {
                counter++;
                Log.d(TAG, ACTION_START + " - "+ counter);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I decreased time interval to 500ms from 1 minute to reproduce problem faster. So now it takes about minute but anyway result is the same:

```
05-27 06:52:04.348 32176-32717/ru.infotecs.intentservice D/BackgroundService: ru.infotecs.intentservice.action.START - 1
05-27 06:52:04.846 32176-32720/ru.infotecs.intentservice D/BackgroundService: ru.infotecs.intentservice.action.START - 1
05-27 06:52:05.349 32176-32726/ru.infotecs.intentservice D/BackgroundService: ru.infotecs.intentservice.action.START - 1
05-27 06:52:05.845 32176-32732/ru.infotecs.intentservice E/Looper: WARNING: The Looper class instance count has over a limit(100). There should be some leakage of Looper or HandlerThread.
05-27 06:52:05.845 32176-32732/ru.infotecs.intentservice E/Looper: Looper class instance count = 101
05-27 06:52:05.845 32176-32732/ru.infotecs.intentservice E/Looper: Current Thread Name: IntentService[BackgroundService]
05-27 06:52:05.845 32176-32732/ru.infotecs.intentservice I/System.out: java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=main,maxPriority=10]
05-27 06:52:05.845 32176-32732/ru.infotecs.intentservice I/System.out:     Thread[main,5,main]
05-27 06:52:05.846 32176-32732/ru.infotecs.intentservice I/System.out:     Thread[Thread-5,5,main]
05-27 06:52:05.847 32176-32732/ru.infotecs.intentservice I/System.out:     Thread[Binder_1,5,main]
05-27 06:52:05.847 32176-32732/ru.infotecs.intentservice I/System.out:     Thread[Binder_2,5,main]
05-27 06:52:05.847 32176-32732/ru.infotecs.intentservice I/System.out:     Thread[IntentService[BackgroundService],5,main]
05-27 06:52:05.848 32176-32732/ru.infotecs.intentservice W/System.err: java.lang.Throwable: stack dump
05-27 06:52:05.848 32176-32732/ru.infotecs.intentservice W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.dumpStack(Thread.java:489)
05-27 06:52:05.848 32176-32732/ru.infotecs.intentservice W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.prepare(Looper.java:105)
05-27 06:52:05.849 32176-32732/ru.infotecs.intentservice W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.prepare(Looper.java:86)
05-27 06:52:05.849 32176-32732/ru.infotecs.intentservice W/System.err:     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:53)
05-27 06:52:05.850 32176-32732/ru.infotecs.intentservice D/BackgroundService: ru.infotecs.intentservice.action.START - 1
```

I wonder how such trivial app may lead to the error. I inspected the IntentService implementation a little bit and found that service is voluntarily stopped after intent handling.

```
private final class ServiceHandler extends Handler {
    public ServiceHandler(Looper looper) {
        super(looper);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        onHandleIntent((Intent)msg.obj);
        stopSelf(msg.arg1);
    }
}
```

Also looper is stopped each time service is destroyed:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    mServiceLooper.quit();
}
```

So I completely have no idea what is wrong. Any ideas?

I use speific device to run my app. It is RugGear RG500. Problem does not reproduce on emulator so it may be a problem of device run-time.

P.S. Currently I got around the problem by coping IntentService implementation to my project with some modifications. I commented out stopSelf method call to keep Looper/Thread alive as much as possible. It does not fix problem completely since Android may stop service in case of memory shortage and start it again lately.

Comment: "Problem reproduces only on this" -- then the manufacturer screwed up their Android build. Buy from a better manufacturer. "Currently I got around the problem by coping IntentService implementation to my project with some modifications" -- if you use the official AOSP implementation of `IntentService`, you should not need any modifications. "It does not fix problem completely since Android may stop service in case of memory shortage and start it again lately" -- that is perfectly normal. If that is a problem for you, your app has bugs that need to be fixed. Processes do not run forever.

Comment: I wish I could select a manufacturer but device is provided by a customer. Unfortunately, I can't change it.

Comment: I just want to point out that you dont have to upload your app to the play store to be able to use push notifications. all the device needs is Google Play Services which it appears this device has

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It takes some time to find out what it is going on since I have not inspected memory leaks previously. It looks like device manufacturer did some instrumentation of the Looper code to track allocations. It just prints the error message and dumps call stack but the application is pretty stable at the same time. I think it is vendor specific code since I didn't find this message in a source code of Android SDK.

If you open memory allocation monitor you will see that memory is steadily allocated during some period of time and finally released. It means that garbage collection was initiated by the JVM. The peak value of allocated memory stays the same during the continuous period of time. It does not grow dramatically over the time as it may be expected.

Also, the error message disappears after GC. I assume that allocation counter is just reset in finalize method of instrumented class.